# Why is my xml doc considered an element?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am trying to load an xml file into an `xmlDocument` but receive an error that it cannot cast the `xmlelement to a xmldocument` why?

**XML**

```
<VR>
  <SubscriberID>xxxx</SubscriberID>
  <EmailAddress>m@gmail.com</EmailAddress>
  <FirstName>m</FirstName>
  <LastName>x</LastName>
  <State>CO</State>
  <Country/>
  <BirthDate>11/16/3004</BirthDate>
  <SendEmail>False</SendEmail>
  <Preference Value="true" Key="life"/>
  <Preference Value="true" Key="yo"/>
</VR>
```

**C# Test**

```
        preferenceHelper target = new preferenceHelper(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        XmlDocument docIn = new XmlDocument();
        docIn.Load(@"C:/INTG/trunk/src/VRI.Integration.Email/Test/xmlIn.xml");
        XmlDocument expected = null; // I know this will fail in the test, but it should compile, right?
        XmlDocument actual;
        actual = target.preferencesXmlDoc(docIn);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");
```

**C# function**:

```
public class preferenceHelper
    {
        public preferenceHelper() { }

        XmlDocument docOut = new XmlDocument();
        public XmlDocument preferencesXmlDoc(XmlDocument docIn)
        {
            foreach (XmlDocument root in docIn.SelectNodes("//VR"))
            {
                foreach (XmlDocument node in root.SelectNodes("//Preference"))
                {
                    XmlNode Name = docIn.CreateElement("Name");
                    Name.InnerText = node.InnerText = node.Attributes["Key"].Value;
                    XmlNode Value = docIn.CreateElement("Value");
                    Value.InnerText = node.InnerText = node.Attributes["Value"].Value;
                    docOut.CreateElement("Property").AppendChild(Name).AppendChild(Value);
                }
            }
            return docOut;
        }

    }
```

**Error**

```
Test method Test.preferenceHelperTest.preferencesXmlDocTest threw exception: 
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.XmlElement' to type 'System.Xml.XmlDocument'.
```

I will not be adding a namespace to the xmlIn, if this is required - how might I load in my xml File?

**Where it fails:** `actual = target.preferencesXmlDoc(docIn);`

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're missing some code. Can you update your question to include the specific block that throws the exception?

Comment: Loaded it in, thanks. I do know that the test will fail do to `expected = null`. But I thought it should at least compile.

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Comment: @Neolisk it is throwing an error within the test file where `actual` is assigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problems are in these statements:

```
foreach (XmlDocument root in SelectNodes(...))
```

foreach implicitly casts each value in the sequence to the type you specify. The statement is expanded to:

```
using(var e = sequence.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (e.MoveNext())
    {
        XmlDocument v = (XmlDocument)e.Current;
        // loop body
    }
}
```

The reason this is crashing with an `InvalidCastException` is that the type of node you're selecting is `XmlElement`, not `XmlDocument`. To fix the issue, simply switch the type in your `foreach` statement to `XmlElement`.

You can also improve readability by using XPath to reach the Preference elements, replacing both loops with a single:

```
foreach (XmlElement node in docIn.SelectNodes("/VR/Preference"))
```

Your outer `SelectNodes` loop is actually completely redundant because `//Preference` will get all `Preference` descendants from the root of the document already, not just from that specific child VR.

Comment: is was actually `XmlElement` that I needed it changed to not `xmlnode`. All answers did help but this answer actually fixed my error.

Comment: @CoryNelson I'm not sure what Default said, but my post does explain why he's having a problem. The difference is that yours went into the minutiae of how `foreach` works.

Comment: @40Alpha I'm not sure why `XmlElement` works here and `XmlNode` doesn't (I'd like to see your finished code), but it's usually best to use `XmlNode` with `SelectNodes()`. `SelectNodes()` will always return `XmlNode`s, but it will _not_ always return `XmlElement`s.

Comment: @JLRishe I used `XMLelement` because I needed to access the attributes and I had issues doing that when using `XmlNode`, that's all. Perhaps there is a better way but I dont know it.

Comment: @40Alpha I see. In that case it is the right choice to use `XmlElement` in this case. The XPath `//Preference` gurarantees that all of the nodes will be elements.

Answer (score 3):

The proplem is here:

```
foreach (XmlDocument root in docIn.SelectNodes("//VR"))
```

and here:

```
foreach (XmlDocument node in root.SelectNodes("//Preference"))
```

`XmlNode.SelectNodes()` returns an `XmlNodeList`, which is an `IEnumerable` of `XmlNodes`. It will not contain any `XmlDocument`s.

So do this:

```
foreach (XmlNode root in docIn.SelectNodes("//VR"))
```

and this:

```
foreach (XmlElement node in root.SelectNodes("//Preference"))
```

Comment: Still throwing that same error, but your answer made sense. Not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

XmlDocument.SelectNodes("//VR") returns an XmlNodeList, not an XmlDocument. So at the least you need to change your code to:

```
public XmlDocument preferencesXmlDoc(XmlDocument docIn)
{
    foreach (XmlNode root in docIn.SelectNodes("//VR"))
    {
        foreach (XmlNode node in root.SelectNodes("//Preference"))
        {
```

Answer (score 0):

A document usually has a header:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Without the header it is considered an element.

Try adding one.

Comment: I tried that, no luck. Either case I would prefer not to add it if possible.

Comment: The XML declaration is an optional part of a document. Its absence does not make it considered an element. `XmlDocument.Load` will load an XML document.